# connect a tableview to a core data relationship

Tags: swift, select, core-data, tableview, relationship

I am working to write a swift app that connects a singer to the songs they wrote. Which means in core data I will have to create a relationshp between 2 core data entites. So a singer can have many songs but a song can only have 1 singer. In class DetailViewController func addName can only add songs to a single singer. What am I missing in my cdoe to make sure songs can only be saved to a specific singer

These are the entites and relatsinoships

ENTITY  NAME
Singer
Attribute Name
singerName - String
Relationship Name
songs
Destination
Song

ENTITY  NAME
Song
Attribute Name
songName - String
Relationship Nam
Singers
Destination
Singer

```
 import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var names: [NSManagedObject] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        fetchNames()
    }

    func fetchNames() {
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
        }

        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Singer")

        do {
            names = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }

    func save(name: String) {
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
        }

        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Singer", in: managedContext)!
        let newName = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: managedContext)
        newName.setValue(name, forKey: "singerName")

        do {
            try managedContext.save()
            names.append(newName)
            tableView.reloadData()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func addName(_ sender: Any) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Add Name", message: "Enter a name", preferredStyle: .alert)

        alertController.addTextField { textField in
            textField.placeholder = "Name"
        }

        let addAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default) { [weak self] _ in
            guard let textField = alertController.textFields?.first, let nameToAdd = textField.text else {
                return
            }
            self?.save(name: nameToAdd)
        }

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

        alertController.addAction(addAction)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return names.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NameCell", for: indexPath)
        let name = names[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = name.value(forKeyPath: "singerName") as? String
        return cell
    }
    

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "DetailViewSegue", sender: indexPath)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "DetailViewSegue",
           let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath,
           let detailViewController = segue.destination as? DetailViewController {
            let selectedName = names[indexPath.row]
            if let fullName = selectedName.value(forKey: "singerName") as? String {
                print("insie")
                print("fullName :", fullName)
                
                print("fullName :", detailViewController.name3)

                detailViewController.name3 = fullName
            }
        }
    }


}

import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
    var name3: String?
    var names: [NSManagedObject] = []
    
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var twoTable: UITableView!
    private let nameLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: .bold)
        return label
    }()
    
    @IBAction func addName(_ sender: Any) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Add Name", message: "Enter a name", preferredStyle: .alert)

        alertController.addTextField { textField in
            textField.placeholder = "Name"
        }

        let addAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default) { [weak self] _ in
            guard let textField = alertController.textFields?.first, let nameToAdd = textField.text else {
                return
            }
            self?.save(name: nameToAdd)
        }

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

        alertController.addAction(addAction)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .purple
        print(name3)

        view.addSubview(nameLabel)
        setupConstraints()

        // Set the name to the label
        nameLabel.text = name3
    }

    private func setupConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            nameLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            nameLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
     
                nameLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.10, constant: 0),
            nameLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),

        ])
        
        nameLabel.backgroundColor = .orange
    }


   
    func save(name: String) {
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
        }

        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Song", in: managedContext)!
        let newName = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: managedContext)
        newName.setValue(name, forKey: "songName")

        do {
            try managedContext.save()
            names.append(newName)
            twoTable.reloadData()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: you should create NSManagedObjectSubClasses from top editor menu after changing class definition of entity to manual definition. 
This give you the classes of Singer and Songs. 
But if Song has only one attribute which is string type then you don't need make separate entity you just make an attribute name as songs with data type Transformable and on right side inspector menu you give type [String] so that will create an array attribute to your entity

Comment: Change `var name3: String?` to `var name3: Singer`? You should take a tutorial on Core Data so you learn how to work with the classes that gets generated for you when you create entities in a Core Data Model. This way you don't have to use declarations like `...: [NSManagedObject]` or use `value(forKeyPath:)` but can use the actual class and property names in your code which will make the code easier to write and understand.